# Unable to resolve maven dependency

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have configured local maven repository in pom.xml. When i build the project it show dependency downloading error(**see the logs below**). Maven is trying to download all dependency from my local maven repository.

Logs

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available

[WARNING] The POM for com.colombia:colombia-core:jar:0.0.17 is missing, no dependency information available

Downloading: http ://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/1.4.2.RELEASE/spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------

-----
[INFO] Total time: 8.334s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 30 07:01:26 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project stream: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.toi.core:stream:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE in central (//xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/) -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 

http:    
//cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Here is my **pom.xml** file

local repository is ***http  ://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local***

```
<repositories>
     <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>XXXXXX</name>
          <url>http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/</url>
          <releases>
             <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
             <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
       </repository>
       <repository>
          <id>springsource-milestones</id>
          <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
       </repository>
    </repositories>
```

**xml.setting**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<!--
 | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
 |
 |  1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user, 
 |                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
 |
 |  2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven
 |                 users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven
 |                 installation). It's normally provided in 
 |                 ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
 |
 | The sections in this sample file are intended to give you a running start at
 | getting the most out of your Maven installation. Where appropriate, the default
 | values (values used when the setting is not specified) are provided.
 |
 |-->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ~/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->

  <!-- interactiveMode
   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
   | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
   | the parameter in question.
   |
   | Default: true
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  -->

  <!-- offline
   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
   | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
   |
   | Default: false
  <offline>false</offline>
  -->

  <!-- pluginGroups
   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
   | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
   |-->
  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
  </pluginGroups>

  <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>

  <!-- servers
   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
   | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
   |-->
  <servers>
    <!-- server
     | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by
     | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
     | 
     | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are 
     |       used together.
     |
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>repouser</username>
      <password>repopwd</password>
    </server>
    -->

    <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
    <server>
      <id>siteServer</id>
      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
    </server>
    -->
  </servers>

  <!-- mirrors
   | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote repositories.
   | 
   | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving certain artifacts.
   | However, this repository may have problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored
   | it to several places.
   |
   | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a mirror reference for that
   | repository, to be used as an alternate download site. The mirror site will be the preferred 
   | server for that repository.
   |-->
  <mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
  </mirrors>

  <!-- profiles
   | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways, and which can modify
   | the build process. Profiles provided in the settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-
   | specific paths and repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment.
   |
   | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus - that needs to know where
   | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide a variable here such that the variable is 
   | dereferenced during the build process to configure the cactus plugin.
   |
   | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles
   | section of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially
   | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular value for the property,
   | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK version prefix, where a 
   | value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'.
   | Finally, the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.
   |
   | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to specifying only artifact
   |       repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form properties to be used as configuration
   |       variables for plugins in the POM.
   |
   |-->
  <profiles>
    <!-- profile
     | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to be activated using one or more of the
     | mechanisms described above. For inheritance purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/>
     | or the command line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique.
     |
     | An encouraged best practice for profile identification is to use a consistent naming convention
     | for profiles, such as 'env-dev', 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 'user-brett', etc.
     | This will make it more intuitive to understand what the set of introduced profiles is attempting
     | to accomplish, particularly when you only have a list of profile id's for debug.
     |
     | This profile example uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and provides a JDK-specific repo.
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.4</id>

      <activation>
        <jdk>1.4</jdk>
      </activation>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    -->

    <!--
     | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env' with a value of 'dev',
     | which provides a specific path to the Tomcat instance. To use this, your plugin configuration
     | might hypothetically look like:
     |
     | ...
     | <plugin>
     |   <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId>
     |   <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
     |   
     |   <configuration>
     |     <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation>
     |   </configuration>
     | </plugin>
     | ...
     |
     | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration whenever someone set 'target-env' to
     |       anything, you could just leave off the <value/> inside the activation-property.
     |
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>target-env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    -->
  </profiles>

  <!-- activeProfiles
   | List of profiles that are active for all builds.
   |
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  -->
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the local repository.
Can you please check whether the
 `org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE` 
is present in the local repo. 
I think it is missing in your local repo. This usually occures when it is unavailable .
Please add it if it is missing. This will fix the issue.

Please check your settings.xml.
Does it have this in pluginRepository tag?

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        </repositories>
            <repository>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and

```
  <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>redhat-techpreview-all-repository</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

If not add these. You should add all your repositories in settings.xml too.

As far as I know the order of the repositories in you pom.xml will also decide the order of the repository access.

As for configuring repos in settings.xml I've read that the order of repos is interestingly enough the inverse order of how the repos will be accessed.

Hope your issue will be solved

Comment: In local maven repository i have configured my customised jar ,For org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE dependency Maven should search at http://repo.maven.apache.org, but it search this jar in my local repository

Comment: If it is present in the error which you got will not come. Go through this path and see whether the required jar "org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE" is present in "http ://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/"

Comment: If you want it from another repository, add that repository too in the <repositories> </repositories>. First it will check in local, then it will check in the repository you specified

Comment: i have already defined , repository location in  <repositories> </repositories> (See pom.xml)

Comment: you meant you need to get it from maven repo?

Comment: Can you please share your .m2/settings.xml file. Because by default it should download from mvn repo. May be something is missing there

Comment: it tries to get all dependencies from my local repository, but ideally what I want to do is hit the maven repo first and if dependencies not present there..then it should hit the local repo.

Comment: Are you getting any jars from maven repo? or issue is only with this jar?

Comment: where can I send you the setting.xml file ?